# Show that Weibull distribution belongs to a one dimensional exponential family

Tags: self-study, distributions, exponential-family

It is given that

$f_\eta(y) = h(y)exp(\eta T(y)-A^*(\eta))$

$P_Y(y)= \frac{k}{\lambda} (\frac{y}{\lambda})^{k-1}exp(-(\frac{y}{\lambda})^k)$

What i did was by arranging $P_Y(y)$ to get $\frac{k}{\lambda ^k} y^{k-1}exp(-(\frac{y}{\lambda})^k)$

so that $lnP_Y(y) = ln(\frac{k}{\lambda^k})+(k-1)ln(y)-(\frac{y}{\lambda})^k$

Therefore

$T(y) = y^{k-1}$

$\eta = -(\frac{1}{\lambda})^k$

$h(y)=\frac{k}{\lambda^k}$

$A^* = -ln(\frac{k}{\lambda^k})= -ln(-k\eta)$

Am i correct?

and how do you work out the mean and variance of Y in terms of $A^*$？

Answer (score 2):

For part one of your question:

No. In case you want to use this particular representation of exponential family [over a more relevant form $h(x)g(\eta) \exp(\eta T(x))$]

\begin{align*}
f_\eta(y) &= h(y)\exp(\eta T(y)-A^*(\eta))\\
\ln f_{\eta}(y) &= \ln h(y) + \eta T(y) - A^*(\eta)\\
P_Y(y) &= \frac{k}{\lambda} (\frac{y}{\lambda})^{k-1}\exp(-(\frac{y}{\lambda})^k)\\
\ln P_Y(y) &= \ln y^{k-1} -(\frac{y}{\lambda})^k  - \ln k  - \ln \lambda^k\\
\ln P_Y(y) &= \ln ky^{k-1}  + \eta (-y^k)    - \ln \eta \text{ where } \eta = \lambda^k\\
\end{align*}